# undefined method `batch_action_admin_news_path' for ActiveAdmin::Helpers::Routes:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Все прекрасно работало. Код в том месте не трогал уже несколько месяцев.

Ругается конкретно на этот блок кода:

```
batch_action :publish do |selections|
    News.find(selections).each do |news|
        News.find(news).toggle!(:published)
    end
    redirect_to admin_news_index_path
end
```

Если оставить только эти две строки:

```
batch_action :publish do |selections|
    # ...
end
```

То ничего не изменится - ошибка сохранится.

С чем это может быть связано, если я вообще все файлы, связанные с gem'ом ActiveAdmin не трогал?

Трогал лишь это: `bundle update` и `install` и работал с ActionCable.

Притом у меня в ActiveAdmin имеют `batch_action` почти все разделы. И там все нормально работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня та-же проблема.
Происходит это из-за неверной генерации роутов.
Модель и ресурс - News. Роут для индексной страницы генерится `batch_action_admin_news_index_path`, а обратиться пытается по `batch_action_admin_news_path`. Решения пока не нашел. Ищу что можно сделать.
Временное решение - переименование ресурса(допустим на NewsPage). [official documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#rename-the-resource)

UPD:
Починил. Всё сводиться к тому что надо для Inherited Resources переопределить дефолтовые имена для роутов(поскольку у него видимо туго с такими моделями как News). В конфиге ресурса админки надо добавить/поправить в блоке `controller`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register News do
  controller do
    defaults :route_collection_name => 'news_index', :route_instance_name => 'news'
  end
end
```

[Inherited Resources docs](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources#overwriting-defaults)

Comment: Да. Это помогло. Но вопрос остается открытым: "Почему это произошло сейчас, спустя столько времени?" ActiveAdmin (вроде) в последнее время не обновлялся...

Comment: Понятия не имею :) Я взялся обновлять 3х-летней давности проект и наткнулся на этот баг. Сейчас у меня получился актуальный ```master```. Еще - если вдруг наткнешься на проблему с потерей градиентный бэкграундов на кнопках и других элементах админки - то это из-за того что миксин АА для градиентов использует ```bourbon``` функцию ```linear-gradient```(ну т.е. её уже нет и ничего он не использует :-D ).
З.Ы. Сделай им issue на гитхабе по нашей проблеме. Может еще кому решение поможет.

Comment: А с пагинацией у тебя проблемы нет случайно? А то у меня каждая кнопка выглядит так `5 (current)` плюс, следовательно, не выделяется текущая страница. Правда этот баг вылез давно, но сильно не напрягает.

Comment: С пагинацией пока не встречал проблем. Попробуй посмотреть правильно ли всё в i18n конфигах. Или почитать доку по kaminari(оно у них за пагинацию отвечает),- может есть кто-то с похожей проблемой в issues в репозитории kaminari.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle update` по умолчанию обновляет **ВСЕ** `gemы` до последней разрешенной (в `Gemfile`) версии. Попробуйте откатить назад все ваши изменения и проверить код еще раз. Для этого хорошо подходит `git bisect`.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что я далеко не профи в Ruby, но я все же и не конченный :)